# Density in fractional Sobolev space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

Suppose $s∈(0,1)$, $D$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Define
$$
H^s=(1−\Delta)^{-s/2}L^2\left(\mathbb{R}^d\right), 
$$
$$
H^s_D=\left\{f\in H^s:f=0 \mbox{  a.e.  on }  D^c\right\}.
$$
Q: Is $C^\infty_c(D)$ dense in $H^s_D$(with norm $\|\cdot\|_{H^s}$) for any open set $D$?

Is there any element reference?

Comment: Not "Dobolev space", but "Sobolev space", in your title. I corrected your typo...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the boundary of $D$ is regular, say $D$ is a bounded domain with Lipschitz boundary, **the density is true.** Equivalent definition of $H^2$ is as follows: $H^s=W^{s,2}$, where
$$
\Vert f\Vert_{W^{2,s}}=\Vert f\Vert_2+\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}
\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|^2}{|x-y|^{n+2s}}\right)^{1/2}
$$
For a proof, see Section 3 in [1]. Now it is relatively easy to prove that a function in $W^{2,s}$ that vanishes in the complement of $D$ can be approximated by $C_0^\infty(D)$. This is more or less contained in Corollary 5.5 in [1].

I am pretty sure that for general domains there are counterexample. If you are interested in irregular domains I can try to find one.

**[1] Di Nezza, E., Palatucci, G., Valdinoci, E.,** [Hitchhiker's guide to the fractional Sobolev spaces.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.4345). *Bull. Sci. Math.* 136 (2012), no. 5, 521-573. 
[(MathSciNet review)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2944369).